# How to write a (MySQL) "LIMIT" in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

How do I convert a MySQL query with LIMIT to a SQL Server query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableEating 
WHERE person = '$identity' 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LIMIT does not work in T-SQL. Use TOP instead:

```
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM tableEating WHERE person = '$identity';
```

As Aaron says, you also need an `ORDER BY` if you don't want to get an arbitrary row.

Comment: Just note that without an `ORDER BY` you're going to get an arbitrary row, and this can change from execution to execution...

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` does not work and `TOP(1)` may also not work in nested statements.

So the right approach is to use `OFFSET... FETCH NEXT`:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

That basically tells TSQL to take one row (`NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY`) starting from the first one (`OFFSET 0`).

Comment: Why do you say that `Top(1)` might not work in a nested statement? I'm curious about this, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Not sure, but I see that it's being discussed here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358682/sql-top-1-syntax-for-a-nested-query

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189463(v=sql.105)) for 2008, later versions work the same way. If you like to do it dynamic use:

```
DECLARE @xCount INT = 20
SELECT TOP(@xCount) * FROM ...
```