# What is the T-SQL equivalent of MySQL syntax LIMIT x, y?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to write a (MySQL) “LIMIT” in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440057/how-to-write-a-mysql-limit-in-sql-server)

How do I change my query with `LIMIT` for SQL-Server?

```
SELECT apretiz FROM tableApoint WHERE price = '$newprice' LIMIT 5;
```

How do I change `LIMIT 5,10`? Can I use `TOP` for it?

Comment: None of the answers below show the syntax for `SELECT *`, so here it is: `SELECT TOP(5) * FROM [TableName]`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As i said it less than one hour ago, you have to use TOP ! (LIMIT is used for MYSQL)

So try to remove `LIMIT 5` and do `SELECT TOP(5) apretiz`.

Also, try to add order by (same reason than before).

Please make a search before asking things. [Link to old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440057/sql-server-how-to-change-mysql-limit/10440085#10440085)

Answer (score 30):

As of SQL Server 2012, you can write

```
...
ORDER BY thisColumn, thatColumn
OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: `FETCH NEXT <N>` is zero indexed so to get the first and only first row do `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY`

Answer (score 7):

Use the `TOP` keyword:

```
 SELECT TOP 5 pretiz 
 FROM tableApoint WHERE price = '$newprice'
```

Using LIMIT 5, 10 is not part of the SQL Standard and is only available in MySQL.

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()` for SQL as a temp solution and will get you the same desired output.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) as row FROM tableApoint 
) a WHERE row >= 5 and row <= 10
```

Answer (score 2):

## SQL Server 2005 and above

If you are using SQL Server 2005 and above, you could use `ROW_NUMBER` function to assign unique numbers to your rows and then pick the range of values from the output.

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    textvalue VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 (textvalue) VALUES
   ('i'),
   ('a'),
   ('e'),
   ('h'),
   ('c'),
   ('l'),
   ('g'),
   ('m'),
   ('d'),
   ('k'),
   ('j'),
   ('f'),
   ('b'),
   ('n');

;WITH letters as
(
    SELECT  textvalue
        ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY textvalue) rownum 
    FROM    table1
)
SELECT  textvalue
FROM    letters
WHERE   rownum  BETWEEN 6 AND 10;
```

*Output*:

```
TEXTVALUE
---------
    f
    g
    h
    i
    j
```