# Difference in limit syntax in sql and mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning database. I came across `LIMIT` keyword and its usage.
In some tutorial it was specified as

`LIMIT row_number OFFSET n` will select row_number of rows after skipping n rows

And in another tutorial it was written as

`LIMIT offset, row_number` will select row_number of rows after skipping offset rows

Now which syntax is correct, if both are correct then where to use what?

Comment: Have you tried them?

Comment: yes i tried them and they are not working together, somewhere the first syntax is working and somewhere the other one, and hence the confusion @DarrenSweeney

Comment: When does the first syntax work but not the second, and vice versa?

Comment: I am using online editors now. And the first syntax is working on sql and second one on mysql, but i'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIMIT row_number OFFSET n` syntax is for MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite

`LIMIT offset, row_number` is for MySQL

Microsoft SQL Server uses a completely different approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10440718/234661

Oracle is similarly difficult: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26051830/234661

Firebird has several methods. The recommended one in Firebird 2.5 and earlier is [`ROWS m TO n`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-dml.html#fblangref25-dml-select-rows), and Firebird 3.0 introduced SQL Standard [OFFSET/FETCH](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-dml.html#fblangref30-dml-select-offsetfetch).

They are different because they haven't been standardized before being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same as they are generating same results.

The difference is only when you use second one `LIMIT offset, row_number`
There is only syntax difference

You can use any of them based on your requirements