# Does JOIN works with LIMIT and OFFSET along WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbeaver

I'm working on spring boot project where I am trying to run following query on both sql client and spring boot code.

```
SELECT two.STORE_NBR, two.TLE_WORK_ORDER_ID, 
       tj.SERVICE_START_TS, tj.SERVICE_END_TS, tj.WIN_NBR 
FROM       TLE_WORK_ORDER AS two 
INNER JOIN TLE_TECHNICIAN_JOB AS tj 
        ON ((two.TLE_WORK_ORDER_ID = tj.TLE_WORK_ORDER_ID)) 
WHERE CREATION_TIMESTAMP LIKE '%2017-11-13%' 
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 2;
```

The data type of CREATION_TIMESTAMP is string.

This query is throwing an error.

Can someone explain that what is the issue with this query?

The query is throwing following error:

> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:133)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:577)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$1(SQLQueryJob.java:486)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:172)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:493)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:894)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3710)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:123)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:172)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:4949)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:872)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:767)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7418)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3274)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:743)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:329)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.lambda$0(JDBCStatementImpl.java:131)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.utils.SecurityManagerUtils.wrapDriverActions(SecurityManagerUtils.java:96)
> at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:131)
> ... 12 more

Comment: Can you update your post with what error your query is throwing? Also what's the DBMS you're dealing with?

Comment: Column CREATION_TIMESTAMP data type?

Comment: @lemon I have updated question with this information. Kindly look at updated question .

Comment: @jarlh it's STRING type

Comment: LIMIT is unknown in sql-server, see: [What is the T-SQL equivalent of MySQL syntax LIMIT x, y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440688/what-is-the-t-sql-equivalent-of-mysql-syntax-limit-x-y)

Comment: Choose a proper date/time data type instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes

Comment: Use `ORDER BY tj.SERVICE_START_TS OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY` in place of `LIMIT 5 OFFSET 2`.

Comment: Reading the (long) error message should have solved the problem. (I do mean this part: "**Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'**" )  The error message indicate that you use [tag:dbeaver], so I added this tag.    Conclusion: Do not be afraid of long error messages, just start reading (and thinking!), line by line

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using SQL-Server, you can't use `LIMIT <N> OFFSET <M>` notation. You should rather use [`OFFSET FETCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/order-by-and-offset-fetch-clause), that uses the `ORDER BY` clause to determine the order of the rows, before truncating your result set.

In your specific query, you seem to be using "*tj.SERVICE_START_TS*", "*tj.SERVICE_END_TS*" as two timestamp fields, to be used in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Your final query should look like:

```
SELECT two.STORE_NBR, two.TLE_WORK_ORDER_ID, 
       tj.SERVICE_START_TS, tj.SERVICE_END_TS, tj.WIN_NBR 
FROM       TLE_WORK_ORDER AS two 
INNER JOIN TLE_TECHNICIAN_JOB AS tj 
        ON ((two.TLE_WORK_ORDER_ID = tj.TLE_WORK_ORDER_ID)) 
WHERE CREATION_TIMESTAMP LIKE '%2017-11-13%' 
ORDER BY tj.SERVICE_START_TS, tj.SERVICE_END_TS 
OFFSET 2 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

*Recommendation*: It's a bad habit to use `VARCHAR` datatypes for date fields, in place of the `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` fields. SQL-Server operates faster and gives you tool to deal with dates.