# SQL TOP 1 Syntax for a nested query

Tags: sql

New to SQL Server and I am trying to use top 1 to get the company with the most order in my DB within my code that is already working but I don't know how to use it properly. Only missing syntax I think.

Query #1 is working fine:

```
SELECT 
    c.CompanyName, COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) as Nombre_Commande 
FROM 
    Orders O
INNER JOIN 
    Customers C ON O.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY 
    c.CompanyName
```

What I am trying to do

```
SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         c.CompanyName, COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) AS Nombre_Commande 
     FROM 
         Orders O
     INNER JOIN 
         Customers C ON O.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
     GROUP BY 
         c.CompanyName)
```

Comment: SELECT TOP (1) * FROM (SELECT c.CompanyName, COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) as Nombre_Commande FROM Orders O
INNER JOIN Customers C
ON O.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
GROUP by c.CompanyName) as TableName

Comment: You will also want to use `ORDER BY` to specify what you want to sort by.  If this is not specified, your rows could come back in arbitrary order, and you may get different results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give the derived table an alias, and also, specifying top without an order by clause is pretty pointless as rows are returned as a set without any order unless the order is explicitly specified with an order by clause:

```
SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM (
  SELECT c.CompanyName, COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) as Nombre_Commande 
  FROM Orders O
  INNER JOIN Customers C ON O.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
  GROUP by c.CompanyName
) AS YourTable
ORDER BY something_meaningful_maybe_nombre_commande?
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 c.CompanyName, COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID) as Nombre_Commande
FROM Orders O INNER JOIN
     Customers C
     ON O.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP by c.CompanyName
ORDER BY Nombre_Commande DESC;
```

This assumes that `Nombre_Commande` is what you want to order by.

By the way, I would be surprised if `COUNT(DISTINCT)` were really needed for this query.  `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(OrderId)` should be sufficient.

Comment: I didn't think you could order by an alias?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid . . . In most dialects of SQL, you can.  I believe it is part of the standard, but not necessarily all databases support it.  For SQL Server specifically, you might be interested in:  http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2010/10/03/why-can-t-we-have-column-alias-in-order-by.aspx.

Comment: What I love about this site... just when I think I know everything I learn something new!